# v-for loop data won't show

Tags: vue.js, axios, shopify

I can't get my v-loop to show the data in my object array. That i got from the API. It's pretty simple, and im sure it should be working. So im wondering if it's something else. The API is not open, so here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z47H8.jpg

```
<div class="" id="buffetfeatured">
    <div v-for="x in product">{{ x.title }}</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({
        el: '#buffetfeatured',
        data() {
            return {
                product: []
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            axios.get('https://ebuffet-dk.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/products.json')
                .then(response => (this.product = response.data.products))
                .catch( error => { console.log(error); });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I know that there are similar examples, and i've tried following them. So im only asking, because im unsure if it's my own fault, or shopify's.

Comment: the api needs credentials, can you give a sample of what it contains?

Comment: are there any errors in the console? is the request returning properly?

Comment: Im sorry here. I took an image. https://imgur.com/a/qIES7Pm

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The data just won't display. I can make it loop out 50 empty div's, but without any content.

Comment: Do you see some content with `<div v-for="x in product">{{ x }}</div>`?

Comment: I get 50 empty's div's inside my loop. Does the code look correct?

Comment: @GrandMaster Just to confirm, even when you try `{{ x }}` inside the loop you still get empty elements?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Try `{{ product }}` outside the loop, dump out the whole thing. To answer your question, there's nothing that looks obviously wrong to me. That said, I don't know how to interpret the picture of the 'response', so I suspect the problem lies in how you're pulling that apart.

Comment: when you process the response with then, try to log what is the response.data

Comment: I did it, https://imgur.com/a/RDnyZOa

Comment: @GrandMaster That looks fine. Could you try putting some fixed content inside the `<div>` elements, just to confirm that something shows up? e.g. `<div v-for="x in product">{{ x }}!!!!</div>`. That should display the `!!!!` part if nothing else. Please could you also try my earlier suggestion of just having `{{ product }}` in your template, without the loop?

Comment: Fixed content is working.

Comment: Where does the template live? You aren't using a server-side framework like Laravel that interprets `{{ ... }}` itself are you?

Comment: Im using shopify. I tried putting it into a template, to see if it made a difference, but it doesn't.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help :-) I posted a solution below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed Vue component within Shopify store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619084/embed-vue-component-within-shopify-store)

Answer (score 1):

Alright for anyone in the future. The problem is shopify is passing {{ }}. Which means that my code won't work.

But here is a solution i stumbled across.

[Embed Vue component within Shopify store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619084/embed-vue-component-within-shopify-store)

Answer (score 0):

youre v-for it is true but it doesn't work because doesn't have any data

this code is wrong ** this.product = response.data.products**

You cannot provide obj equal to arry you should push obj to array

```js
this.product.push(response.data.products)
```