# Using Vue in Shopify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, shopify, liquid

We have installed vue webpack-simple, not using the Vue CDN and having difficulties using liquid to render the order total with `{{ cart.total_price }};`

We are trying to show a message in the cart the looks at the order value and minuses this from max shipping limit to show a free shipping message or the value needed to qualify for free shipping. We have a number of variables that we are trying to store the `{{ product.price }}` to but we are not able to render this in the vue file.

We have this working using delimiters via the CDN in liquid files, but not in a .vue file with `<template></template>`

Here is the code created so far;

```html
<template>
    <div :class="$style.cartBackground" v-show="showPromo">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-0">
            {{ cartPromo }}
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      showPromo: false,
      firstMessage: 'Can we tempt you? Spend another',
      secondMessage: 'and get free shipping',
    }
  },

  methods: {

  },
  computed: {
    cartPromo() {
      const cartTotal = 10000;
      const maxShipping = 100000;
      const priceFiltered = '49.99';
      parseInt(priceFiltered);
      const displayCartPrice = cart.total_price;
      var productPrice = $('money').val();

        if (cartTotal < maxShipping) {
          return this.firstMessage  + ' $' + ((maxShipping - cartTotal) / 100 ).toFixed(2) + ' ' + this.secondMessage;
        } else if (cartTotal > maxShipping) {
          return 'You have qualified for Free Shipping';
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<style module>

.cartBackground {
  background-color: #F1DAE4;
  border: 1px solid #F1DAE4;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: where is the cart object coming from?

Comment: The cart object is being pulled in fro our cart.lquid page template using the following HTML and lquid.  <td class="text-right"><span class="money">{{cart.total_price | money}}</span></td>

Comment: Why not use the [current version of Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) instead of 3+ year old Webpack template?

Comment: But cart is a liquid object. Where are you transforming it into a javascript object?

Comment: Please check if this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619084/embed-vue-component-within-shopify-store/56626402#56626402